# How to work with Mercurial in IntelliJ?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

There is a support for Mercurial in IntelliJ, but it does not handle renames correctly. I.e. renaming a file or moving a file to another package does not rename/move file in Mercurial.

This is absolutely annoying. Is there a better way to work with Mercurial in IntelliJ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register your Mercurial root in Settings | Version Control.
There you have to point to exact root directory, you can't use the "`<Project>`" mapping if the hg root is above it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by incorrect VCS roots configuration in IDEA, [check the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65459) with the solution in the comments.

Specifying the mercurial root directory explicitly instead of using the `<Project>` placeholder should help.

Comment: My project directory is not the root of a Mercurial repository and it cannot be, since the repository contains other stuff as well. Do you mean that IntelliJ-Mercurial integration only works correctly with respect to renames if the project root is also the repo root? Please, say no.